# OpenCV/C++ functions

Tags: c++

I came across functions used like this:

```
void func(int, void*);

int main()
{
  func(0,0);
}

void func(int, void*)
{
  //content
}
```

And I have no idea, what does it mean. But for some reason, if I copied content from func straight into main, it doesn't work.
I found it used with OpenCV, but no explanation of it.

So I would appreciate, if someone could explain to me what does it mean or why is it used.

So, in my case:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void* );

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /// Load source image and convert it to gray
  src = imread( "test.png", 1 );

  /// Convert image to gray and blur it
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

  /// Create Window
  char* source_window = "Source";
  namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( source_window, src );

  thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

  waitKey(0);
  return(0);
}

/** @function thresh_callback */
void thresh_callback(int, void* )
{
  Mat threshold_output;
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

  /// Detect edges using Threshold
  threshold( src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY );

  /// Find contours
  findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

  /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects
  vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
  vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );

  for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) { 
    approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
    boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
  }

  /// Draw bonding rects
  Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );;
  for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) {
    rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), Scalar::all(255), 2, 8, 0 );
  }

  /// Show in a window
  namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Contours", drawing );
}
```

This is code, that I get from the internet. It works well, it detects edges and draw rectangle around them and i can understand it, except declaration of function thresh_callback.
So, my main question is, why it doesn't work without it?
And what does parameters without names mean or why are they there?

Comment: Every basic beginner's book of c++ explains that. What don't you understand specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
void func(int, void*);
```

declares that there will be a `void` function called `func` with two parameters, the first being an `int` and the second being a `void*`.

2.

```
void func(int, void*)
{
  //content
}
```

This is the definition of the function declared in 1. So, if you call `func`, this function will be executed.

3.

```
int main()
{
  func(0,0);
}
```

Here you execute `func` and pass `0` as the first parameter and `0` as the second parameter as well.

4.

If you paste the content of `func` into main, then it will not work, since the content of `func` assumes the existence of the two parameters, which do not exist in `main`.

Comment: Thanks for answer,
And if parameters have no names? How they could be used?

Comment: @MrKew, that's basically due to the freedom of implementation. The declaration explicitly asks for the existence of those parameters and the implementation cannot allow itself to not have them, however, if they are not actually needed, then they will remain nameless. If they were not actually used, then your error when you had the functionality in your main might have been that the function was not implemented. An error message would tell me more about the issue.

Comment: There is no error message, without function it simply draws rectangle as dot in left-top corner. So some of OpenCV functions needs to be in another function with int and void* arguments?

Comment: @MrKew, I am afraid I lack the information to find out the exact situation you are in. Please edit your question, which should contain the code in the two separate cases and the explanation of the difference between the behaviors. Most of us will not run your code, just look at your question and leave it unanswered if there is not enough information. I try to help, but my knowledge about your problem is very limited.

Comment: Well, for some reason it is working now, it was probably some typing error, which is strange, because no error messages appeared. Anyways thanks for your time.